# How to Calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient between the bits of a 32 bit Hash value?

Tags: correlation, hash

I am new to statistics. I am checking the uniformity of the hash functions. There are examples to find the correlation between two values. I don't know how to find the correlation between the bits of a single hash value.
Please help me in finding the Pearson correlation coefficient between the bits of a single hash value.

Comment: Welcome to this site! It sounds to me like it would be more interesting to study whether every hashcode is realizable for a given set of items or whether two distinct items could possibly map to the same hashcode (collision), which calls for a histogram, a QQ-plot or statistcal test of uniformty. Why are you interested in correlation?

Comment: Hi,if there is no correlation between them then we can say that the bits are randomly distributed.After that through plotting the correlation coefficient matrix we can study how the correlations dissipate for the inputs.